# Custom charts in highchairs

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart, customization, linechart

I am trying to plot the chart as shown below
[image]

Not sure what to search for as this is a combination of three charts on same chart.Any starting point will help

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the chart like that, you can use the Highcharts Stock with combination of three series:
`line`, `flags` and `column`.

**Sample demo you can base on:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/87tbj5x2/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.flags
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.flags.shape
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column